# jquery , html form produce a different output after first time

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

html in delete_define.php  follows:

```
<form action="delete_now.php"  onsubmit="my_funct();">
    <input type="submit" name="my_submit" class="my_submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

javascript snippet follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        function my_func(){
           alert("from within my_func()");
        }
    });
</script>
```

delete_now.php content is:

```
 //php code snippet **[THIS LINE IS AN EDIT]**

    <script type="text/javascript">

    alert("from within delete_now.php");
</script>
```

For the first time when i run the script, I see the form button, click on the button and in chrome console find the message 'my_func() is not defined.'  and instantly the browser shows the alert box from delete_now.php and no error msg in console exists. the url of the page changes from http://localhost/soc_net/delete_now.php to http://localhost/soc_net/delete_now.php?my_submit=submit.

If i try to run delete_define.php for the second time without closing the browser, I don't see the form button. If I close the browser and reopen it, then same situation repeats on.

What I want:

1) Form button will show up on every run.

2) I'll click on the submit button then my_func() will be executed and ONLY AFTER it gets executed that delete_me.php will be called

3) first the php code in the delete_me.php will be executed and ONLY AFTER that the javascript code in that page will be executed.

Anyone around plz?

**EDIT 2 :**

delete_now.php has a call to javascript function stopUpload:

```
window.top.window.stopUpload('<?php echo $uploaded_file_name;  ?>');
```

this function is defined in the delete_define.php page.

the php code snippet in delete_now.php has a session variable which takes a random value each time. that value is used from within stopUpload(), but unfortunately stopUpload can't receive the changing session value. it uses the value received at the very first time.

How can i make it receive the changed value?

i think stating the problem (server side, client side mixing  prob) will need no code.

**FINAL EDIT :
I THINK MY 2ND EDIT IS WORTH ASKING A NEW QUESTION ABOUT SERVER SIDE AND CLIENT SIDE PROGRAMMING. SO I AM GONNA DO THAT. I'LL TELL THE URL OF THE NEW QUESTION HERE**

**[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740764/session-variable-does-not-get-updated-within-javascript-code) is the new question.**

Comment: my_func needs to moved outside of $(document).ready(function()...

Comment: why? why is it shown that 'my_func() is not defined'?

Comment: Because my_func defined in scope of function that run on page load and it's not accessible outside of that function. That's why when onsubmit event happend your functions is not accessible!

Comment: ur suggestion did not work however

Comment: Just a quick sanity check question - How are you populating `$uploaded_file_name` ? Also, you can prevent the URL change by setting the `method` property of the form to `POST` instead of leaving it as default (`GET`)

Comment: actually the form(for uploading a file) in delete_define has an iframe as targer. the $uploaded_file_name is the file name that gets uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answers to your questions:

1) If I understand correctly you want to show Submit button in  "Delete_Now.php" as well as "Delete_Define.php" So I recommend put same html code in that page too.

2) If you want to run my_func() n form submit here is the code that I can suggest:

```
<form action="delete_now.php"  onsubmit="return my_func();">
    <input type="submit" name="my_submit" class="my_submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_func(){
       alert("from within my_func()");
       return true;
    }
</script>
```

3) You cannot run server-side (php) code AFTER client-side code (JavaScript). However there is a workaround to do so but I don't recommend it: First return the page content with Javascript code that you want to display to client and DO NOT do any other action oh PHP-side and then after do your client-side make a callback or Ajax Call to server to do what you wanted to do on php.

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: 1) and 2) fine. AS to 3) what is that workaround ? i wanted to execute js after php in delete_now.php , NOT php after js

Comment: Sorry I thought you want to run PHP After Javascript. In that case your code should work without issue :-)

Comment: why to use onsubmit="return my_func();" instead of onsubmit="my_func();" ?