# Session variable does not get updated within javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

delete_define.php has the following code snippet:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<form action="delete_now.php" target="upload_target"  onsubmit="return my_func_1();">
    <input type="submit" name="my_submit" class="my_submit" value="submit"/>
    <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src1111="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_func_1(){
       //alert("from within my_func() =" +<?php echo $_SESSION['my_session'];  ?>);
       alert(" my_func_1");
       return true;
    }

    function my_func_2(){
       alert("my_func_2 =" +<?php echo $_SESSION['my_session'];  ?>);
       return true;
    }
</script>
```

delete_now.php has:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['my_session']=rand();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">   
    alert("from within delete_now.php = " +<?php echo $_SESSION['my_session'];  ?>);
    window.top.window.my_func_2();
</script>
```

The problem is my_func_2() does not give the same output for the session variable as the alert box in delete_now.php gives.

Why is that?

```
EDIT: CHANGED THE CODE SAID TO BE IN delete_define.php
```

Comment: my_func_2() - What is it? Where it's defined?

Comment: ...and where did you define `my_func_2()`, exactly?

Comment: oh, im editing my post. don't mind plz

Comment: edited the mistaken part

Comment: @devdRew, may I request you to have a look at a php, mysql question here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13025264/mysql-preventing-new-entries-within-calculation-time

Comment: @devdRew, can you please have a look at a css, jquery question on a different topic here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137378/div-above-another-div-but-should-scroll-beneath-the-later-one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when the delete_define.php was loading the Session var was one, then it's become another, but in you JS stored previous value.

You should store session var into JS var, and then in JS in delete_now.php reset it with the fresh value.

[How to refresh value from frame and other situations](http://sharkysoft.com/tutorials/jsa/content/053.html)

Add to first php file's JS something like:

```
var session_var = '<?php echo $_SESSION['my_session']; ?>';
```

And then in your delete_now.php's JS:

```
parent.session_var = '<?php echo $_SESSION['my_session']; ?>';
```

And change function my_func to alert session_var JS variable.

Think so...

Explanation:

Then result page js will be:

```
function my_func_2(){
   alert("my_func_2 = 13513513513513");
   return true;
}
```

So when you call it, whatever is in the $_SESSION is, there will be old, static value.

Overall process description:

1. Load delete_define.php
2. Javascript var, containing actual filename initialized
3. From submits
4. Script delete_now.php is runing
5. Javascript var in main window refreshes
6. You call my_func_2() which use you global JS var, containing fresh filename.

Comment: actually the form in delete_define.php uploads  image files (I excluded unnecessary parts of my code while posting the question). The session variable is stored in a php variable in my_func_2() and that variable is then used as the image file name to append it to an html div. so if i keep the file name in a js variable I can't use that as the  filename in the image tag of the html code. have I clarified it?

Comment: You can, cause you will change JS var value in second file by `window.top.window.session_var = '<?php echo $_SESSION['my_session']; ?>';` If I understood you well. Other case, explain the overall process. Where and how you're uploading, reloading page or not...

Comment: the form has an iframe as the target. so no page reloading. php uploading code is done in delete_now.php

Comment: so, I were right. When first PHP script loaded, you create JS var with CURRENT session var value. Then when the second PHP script runs on the form submit, it's refresh your JS var with the CURRENT session var value.

Comment: is js variable as global as like php session var here? otherwise how will the js var from within my_func_2 will access the same js var in delete_now.php?

Comment: my code within my_func_2 is : $uploaded_file_name=$_SESSION['my_session']; $(".photo_upload_preview_indiv:last").append('<div class="photo_upload_preview_indiv"><img src="uploads/<?php echo $uploaded_file_name; ?>"/></div>');  Suppose the js variable that holds the image file name is my_js_var. so how can in use my_js_var in place of $uploaded_file_name in the line <img src="uploads/<?php echo $uploaded_file_name; ?>"/>

Comment: same as you call JS function from frame. You access var in delete_define.php BY `window.top.window.session_var` and refresh it to the actual state.

Comment: if `$uploaded_file_name` is $_SESSTION['my_session'], then change code to $(".photo_upload_preview_indiv:last").append('<div class="photo_upload_preview_indiv"><img src="uploads/' + session_var + '"/></div>');, where `session_var` is always actual due to refreshing wich is done in frame.

Comment: ' due to refreshing wich is done in frame.' how to do that refreshing/

Comment: `window.top.window.session_var = '<?php echo $_SESSION['my_session']; ?>';` in your delete_now.php

Comment: [how to access vars in frames](http://sharkysoft.com/tutorials/jsa/content/053.html) JS: parent.session_var = 'refreshed value';

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6419/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-devdrew)

Comment: Error messages.. saying what?

Comment: u said that the session vaiable within my_func_2 does not get updated as expected, coz the function holds the previous session value. But when the session was changed from delete_now and the call for my_func_2() was made from there, then the session var within my_func_2 should contain the updated value. But that does not happen. Explanation plz

Comment: Because `echo $your_var` just echoed it ones and thats all, PHP script runned once, and than it's just plain HTML/Javascript. Calling function my_func() won't go to PHP $_SESSION var everytime, just once, while page generation, and then the value of the Session var is `hardcoded` in you JS function as shown in answer.

Comment: if there is no questoions any more, close the question.

Comment: can u refer me any online resource regarding server side and client side code mixing?

Comment: .the value of the Session var is hardcoded ,- why hardcoded instead of  existing as a variable ? any online resource to know in details?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it more clearly, but... You put it into JS, JS is a static text, it doesn't refer to PHP after the PHP script is finished. After the PHP code is work out, you've got: `alert("my_func_2 = 25351385135");` not `alert("my_func_2 =" +<?php echo $_SESSION['my_session'];  ?>);`

Comment: may I request u to visit this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960740/jquery-change-jqueryui-dialog-box-content-from-a-ajax-call-in-the-webpage ? Is there any other systematic way to invite a user to answer a question?

Answer (score 0):

you have assigned random number, so based on the order you run the page will give alert,
if you start from delete_now.php two consecutive alerts will be same . first assign some static value and then check

Comment: static value won't cause the prob arise. the prob i stated in my post does actually occur