# jquery, change jqueryui dialog box content from a ajax call in the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/)  is used to show a dialog box, then if there is a click the 'dialog_insider' on the dialog box ,not on the flat (correct wording?) webpage , an ajax call will be made. The file in the called through the ajax 
html:

```
<div id="dialog" style="border:1px solid green; width:150px; margin:auto;">
    <div class="dialog_insider">this is the dialog</div>
    <!-- end of class dialog_insider-->    
</div>
<!- end of id  dialog-->
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dialog").click(function(){

            my_dialog = $(this).clone();
            my_dialog.dialog();
            $(".dialog_insider", my_dialog).click(function(){
                alert("clicked");
                $.post("replace.php",function(response){
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

the file replace.php contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("hi");
        $("dialog_insider",my_dialog).html('4444444');
    });
</script>
```

I don't get any functionality(i.e. no alert, no html changing) from the replace.php page

I tried with `$("opener.dialog_insider",my_dialog).html('4444444');`, but no result.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make javascript from ajax-called page running, you need to apped it to the current document.

And `opener` won't work when you make an AXAJ call, works only with opened window.

```
$.post("replace.php", {}, function(response){
    $('body').append(response);
});
```

JS will execute when you append it, or make `eval()`;

Comment: ' you need to apped it to the current document' - is it only for dialog box? otherwise, I think it is not obligatory to write some thing as the body of a call back function

Comment: Chrome console says : Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined

Comment: `$('body')`, selector for the `<body />` element. (`$(body) => $('body')`)

Comment: About the first comment, yes, it's not obligation, you can use `eval()` I've wrote about it. Two ways of execute JS - `eval()`, and append it to the document, to get browser know about what it needs to execute.

Comment: 'opener .. works only with opened window' -isn't dialog box an open window?

Comment: if no dialog box were here, i think my code for a simple ajax call with a blank callback function-body would work.

Comment: gets the 'hi' alert from replace.php but the html does not get changed

Comment: selector must be `$('.dialog_insider')` in your `replace.php`

Comment: why? I want to change the html on the modal window

Comment: You don't understand that the **modal window is't window as a window object**, it's just a DIV... First read about what you're using, then do it. We are here not to teach basics.

Comment: may I request you to have a visit at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554666/type-show-a-name-list-like-facebook-status-box ? I do not know whether such a request is valid in SOF.